# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database" [Geofire issue]

Tags: flutter, firebase, cocoapods

As there is constant update with firebase plugins I run into cocopod errors, what exactly is this error and how do I resolve this ?
I have had one before and resolved it but with newer packages and older plugins this error keeps popping up.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `GeoFire` from `https://github.com/jesussmile/geofire-objc.git`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    GeoFire (from `https://github.com/jesussmile/geofire-objc.git`) was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
      GeoFire/Database (= 4.3.0) was resolved to 4.3.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (= 9.3.0)

    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.3, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a copy of the `geofire-objc` repository then in the file `GeoFire.podspec` changed  `db.ios.dependency 'Firebase/Database', '10.0.3'` to the firebase database version i was using , in this case 10.0.3 . Now its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added

```
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/mrdishant/geofire-objc'
```

in your Podfile?

Add it under

```
target 'Runner' do

.....
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/mrdishant/geofire-objc'
.....

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pod clean`. For cleaning pod files and caches.

It's done using `pod install` for installing pod files.

Comment: yup already done it

Comment: thats the latest version

Comment: Try to update your GeoFire package. Because Your GeoFire package requires firebase database version 9.3.0 but you have been using 10.0.0 so you have to update the GeoFire package or reduce the version of firebase_database to 9.3.0

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, I placed

```
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/mrdishant/geofire-objc'
```

into

```
target 'Runner' do

.....
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/mrdishant/geofire-objc'
.....

end
```

but I also changed my platform `` from :ios, "10.0" to "12.0" in Pod file```